# Fatal signal 11 error in Cocos2d-x Android pass a variable to a global variable?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I defined a global variable outside the fuctions in .cpp file. Like the `Rules` below. I want to pass a variable to Rules in `SetRulesFunc`. But I got the

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xe72d2d24 (code=1), thread 26592 (Thread-61675)
```

error . Is it right to do this ? I found that if the variable passed to Rules is short, everything is OK . But when the variable become longer error happened. I got "libc fatal signal 11" error.

My environment: cocos2d-x 2.1.5, Android application using NDK

CLuaScriptReader.cpp

```
#include "LuaScriptReader.h"

string Rules;

CLuaScriptReader::CLuaScriptReader(){
...
}

void CLuaScriptReader::SetRulesFunc(CCString* rules){
    CCLog("SetRulesFunc(CCString* rules)");     
    Rules = string(rules->getCString());
}
```

UPDATE: [here](https://github.com/einverne/writing/blob/new_writing_app/Classes/LuaScriptReader.cpp) is my whole `LuaScriptReader.cpp`. Please help.

Comment: When you say "longer", how long would that be?

Comment: Most likely getCString gives you a temporary pointer to a char* whose memory will be cleaned up by CCString as the string goes out of scope. If making a proper copy of the string returned by getCString fixes the issue, then you know that that's the case.

Comment: Also, I assume that `string` is really `std::string`?

Comment: It's possible that something has overwritten `Rules`. Do you have any arrays nearby?